# LINQ queries seems to wait on TryGetConnection() during performance tests

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL for connecting to SQL Server database from my web application. When running performance test with 20 concurrent users, I'm seeing calls waiting on TryGetConnection(). I use minimum connections in connection pool to be 20 in connection string.  Any ideas on getting around this issue?

ASP.Net MVC 5
.Net 4.5
SQL Server 2008 R2
I use dynaTrace for capturing the performance in server side.

Comment: Connections are not released back to the pool until they are closed or disposed and the GC collects them. If you are running 20 consecutive users, you should probably have 2 or 3 times that many connections available in your pool. If you don't specify how many in the connection string, the default is 100.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. As you do not have enough connections available your .net code waits in TryGetConnection(). thats also why dynatrace shows you this is the method where you wait. Dynatrace will also show you Database Connection Pool size and Usage -> just check the Database Dashlet